# Bootstrapping Play Application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, bootstrapping

I want to run some code on starting a Play Application. This does not seem to work. Any clues ?

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Logger.info("Foo Fee Fi");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your Global class in the default package? It should be, otherwise you have to define its location in `application.conf`:

```
# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
global=mypackage.MyGlobal
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you are extending the wrong object or have put your object in the wrong package.  For more details check out the docs on the Global object for [Java](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaGlobal) or [Scala](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaGlobal).